# Windows Task Scheduler User Account Details & Unknown 'INTERACTIVE' User

Tags: windows, powershell, authentication, windows-task-scheduler, user-accounts

In the Windows Task Scheduler, I'm looking for a way to determine the specific User Account Details for a given task (*ideally using PowerShell*) ... not just the 'UserName', that is easy to find.  But perhaps the `SID` of the user account bound to a given task under the following section:

```
> Windows (Server or Desktop)
>> Task Scheduler (`taskschd.msc`)
>>> Task Properties
>>>> Security Options
>>>>> When running the task, use the following user account:
>>>>>> (either...)    
>>>>>> • Run only when user is logged on    
>>>>>> • Run whether user is logged on or not
```

For example, I have the following 'Adobe Acrobat Update Task' Scheduled Task:

[image: Adobe Acrobat Update Task]

... and as you can see, the user is 'INTERACTIVE'.  But there is no 'INTERACTIVE' user account on the machine, yet the task is running successfully ...

[image: Adobe Acrobat Update Task - History]

... so I'm trying to find the details for the 'INTERACTIVE' user, in this specific instance.

I also tried to create another task and enter 'INTERACTIVE' for the user, but it wouldn't accept it.?.

[image: New Task - Select User - Error]

... so how can 'INTERACTIVE' work for the existing Task; when it does not exist & you cannot create a new task with it.?.

The closest I could come to finding the details of a Scheduled Task in PowerShell or CommandLine was:

```
schtasks.exe /query /V /FO CSV > schtasks.csv
```

... but this does not give any more information than 'UserName'.

Comment: `INTERACTIVE` is not an account or group - it's a _label_ that Windows attaches to the security tokens requested from interactive logon sessions (like when you log into your machine at the console or via RDP)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen but the label then must reference an account at some point, yes?..  so how do I determine information regarding the label?  And/or is there documentation regarding creating tasks with labels?